# Problem with Determinant calculating using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a very small code just to see how i can perform operations on matrices and determinants using python pandas DataFrames. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
r1=eval(input("Enter 1st row: "))
r2=eval(input("Enter 2nd row: "))
r3=eval(input("Enter 3rd row: "))
ds=pd.DataFrame([r1,r2,r3])
c=0                                      #c for column
r=0                                      #r for row
while c<3:
    r=0
    while r<3:
        if type((c+r)/2)=="float":
            ds[c][r]=(ds[c][r])*(-1)
            r+=1
        elif type((c+r)/2)=="int":
            pass
            r+=1
    c+=1
print(ds)
```

Let me brush you up with the program. I am inputting each row of a 3x3 determinant from the user. Then I am integrating all the three rows into the Pandas DataFrame.

Initializing c=0 and r=0 (c for column number and r for row number).

The while loop is for applying sign convention on the determinant, that is, if sum of row number and column number is even, multiply that element with +1 or else multiply with -1. The if statement is checking whether the sum is even or odd.

When i run the program, it asks all the 3 input commands. But, after that it doesn't show the updated DataFrame ( after sign convention) as i have given a print statement in the end.

I checked if it is going somewhere wrong with the row and column number updating (c+=1 and r+=1), but iam not quite able to see any wrong in that, neither is the program giving me any error.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python 2 version than in that case your code
if type((c+r)/2)=="float   , is wrong because int divide by int give int and you are checking for float